# .NET Exception Page Not Human Readable

Tags: asp.net, exception

I'm running a local dev server on Windows 7 with IIS 7.5, .Net 4.  Sometimes I get exceptions on one of my sites that don't come out as the normal yellow background red font screen, but as a bunch of symbols that aren't legible.  I've never had this happen on any other computer, it's difficult to describe.

> �X�o�8����Q��5m�X�Utc�&����銐����;�N����~�Nڦ[v�t��ISc����l�����������Q���v���#�g76�D�9��̀ ,��3S�4Fa<����&4'���la��b�i%l��y'�n)���)��eT��SmcdZ�R�(U.a���3��[a��k���W��1H7sHRE���3&���L�&�����f���o����Ľ����`a�dL�H��Y��Q��/��9(!*�����(��lH��0��[^tk#N�{���9e��T�qmP��Wb1��mL�"����vp��9;�4�ʴ׮e�R( �f X��� �i"��8�Ʉ�ʔ�f���Xu� Ԋ�����` �9\    �:d1��~���������hl|!U̢lJ����ƭ@FR���4���ʺYB�j���}Usj���Ԃk���,�dNϩ�4Tk-�/b9(D�8a3f���|x���̞�eA ���Mk0H�wɩ,5��17Xu���@u�XB�D��"��]T�ĺ=������m?w�݀ޮ �]˷�|��b0r!$���T�o���贏�^F�G.�D��k���$rv�̪�F��l��7��k�l�]#�k��h��]�n��.�;�����\q^+(K0��ܯtg�#՟�J݂_Q��~{��1��dr1�ڎ��>����/Q;g�k�NW@*,�ت�Y�IV2e�6�DS%Z�pFi��fvK��)(�R�T�g2��B{�rhl�"g\bI%���n7� dj2�1m��c��̪(\ܝZ�w�9jM�/s�h��K:��Hg��攸�����\��]ߵ��������TQ���Ʒ�vs�wh(l;���������Y�pB����K��;�8N� M?eFD-�u�Ww�I��)�L��,�.y�Xi�=`��!۲[t���"���2ĥK�J|���f����lJRY�^gƹ5���n�NVΆ?����gc4���~���*����{{��ْ��R��3� R��Nȍ|b�'�Kc�^M?�Y��������.U�{ø�3����\S�r�]�6%����3%��M�I����I7P�.�( �:���)��s�I.��.�)��U�z�y�y�^�f��;0ϗ�'%d�.��ڑV�Ϟ�@I-��ߎ���b1�}�r1��ս��Nc��ޙ[t���x���wMw�cW������Ň��*��Շ;��c���y���U9��d�r��������I�.Nz��Z]��9l� l<��k�,u��Aь��ޔ�ޱ�u'�͕>��������+���زęɾ��V�,K����1������Nf��p����sʩ�/7K������ٟ,���q"S�����G��JJ����&>������ݽ���&�G��c���������ۯ�P/  �����!+-u����&�?Ȝ���FX﫢�Z+��CwL�5�A!���"{�z�!S�IG���

Sometimes if I debug it it will catch the exception and I can view the message, but sometimes it won't.  Other exceptions produce the standard error screen, this only happens occasionally.

Has anybody else every experienced this?  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: `it's difficult to describe.`  In that case, can you take a screenshot?

Comment: I just joined the site so I don't have the reputation to post images yet, I tried.  It's just a white screen with the characters I pasted above.

Comment: Can you use fiddler to look at the result?

Comment: maybe it has something to do with page's encoding or http compression? did you play with any of those?

Comment: Fiddler shows the same, attempting fixes right now from the possible duplicate link above as it does sound similar.  I searched a lot for existing answers but it's a tough thing to search for.  Will report back shortly

Comment: @Mike Voting to close as dupe. The question dugas linked to will most likely answer the OP's question. The answer he's received is just a worse version of what's there.

Comment: Setting the Response.Filter = null in Application_Error did resolve the issue, thanks guys, that was incredibly fast and thorough!  I love this place.  I guess this was a duplicate question, sorry

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your output was gzip encoded in http, but your browser isn't decoded them as such.

Comment: The dupe suggestion has a more comprehensive version of this answer.